# filter_by in sqlalchemy giving error 2 arguments passed but I have only one

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
search_api(session, search_obj, entity):
query = ''
count = 0
print search_obj
for entry in search_obj:
    print entry
    query += str(entry) + " = " + str(search_obj[entry])
    count += 1
    if(count != len(search_obj)):
        query += " , "
obj_list = session.query(entity).filter_by(str(query))
print obj_list
return (obj_list)
```

I am getting the following error

> TypeError: filter_by() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Your original attempt at querying would possibly expose you to SQL injection. You explicitly subvert protections offered by SQLAlchemy by passing in SQL text, formed by concatenating strings from who-knows-where.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by), `filter_by` takes a `**kwargs` argument.

For instance:

```
session.query(entity).filter_by(my_column = "value")
```

If you have a multiple criteria you want to group with a "and", you can store them in a `dict` and use it like this:

```
criteria = {'col1': 'value1', 'col2': 'value2'}
session.query(entity).filter_by(**criteria)
```

In your situation, "criteria" is the same as "search_obj" variable…

Comment: Now I have used obj_list = session.query(entity).filter_by(**search_obj)  it working now thanks

Comment: @katrik: All right, but don't forget to query with `all()`: `session.query(entity).filter_by(**search_obj).all()`

Comment: Do you need more explanation? I suggest you to upvote and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/344471) my answer.